# How to increase inodes limit in ReiserFS filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, quota, inode, reiserfs

Is it possible to increase inode limit in ReiserFS without formatting the partition?

Currently, the filesystem on my VPS allows me to create 489K inodes, which is not enough. The machine works as online server so disk format is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

1. In the general case, you can't increase your inode limit without reformatting.
2. [ReiserFS doesn't use inodes](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/8658/).
3. Don't use ReiserFS... it's as dead as Mrs. Reiser... though I suppose she'd probably prefer Mrs. Sharanova, considering.